# get data according to recordTypeId

Tags: apex, soql, record-type

I have two Objects, Account and FavoriteAccounts__c with a relationship (master-detailed) , Account has many RecordTypes (New,Prof,..)

I want to get All favorite accounts according to Account record type, I tried this

```
List<Account> accounts {set; get;} 
List<FavoriteAccounts__c> favorites {set; get;} 
String accountType {set; get;}

public PageReference getFav(){

accountType = Apexpages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('selectedAccount');

favorites = [SELECT Account.id, Account.Name 
             FROM FavoriteAccounts__c 
            WHERE Account__r.RecordTypeId IN (SELECT id 
                                              FROM RecordType 
                                              WHERE name=: accountType)];

}
```

but I got this Compile Error: The left operand 'Account__r.RecordTypeId' cannot have more than one level of relationships.

how could I do that ?

Comment: Your IN clause suggests a collection of recordtype objects. I think you may need a collection of ids. I could be mistaken hence the comment instead of an answer.  A single SOQL may require the old map keyset trick  or you can get the IN clause collection via an assigned variable holding the ids from a prior separate SOQL

Comment: yes the problem in IN clause, because i replaced it with Account__r.RecordTypeId =: [SELECT id FROM RecordType WHERE name=: accountType]; .. and It works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what data do you actually need, the accounts that have been favoured or do you want all FavouredAccount records for further processing?

I am also wondering why you are using a PageReference to load those records?

A quickfix would be just filtering directly on Account__r.RecordType.Name

```
favorites = [SELECT Account.id, Account.Name 
             FROM FavoriteAccounts__c 
            WHERE Account__r.RecordType.Name =: accountType];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple solution

```
Set<Id> accId = new Set<Id>();

    for(Account a:[SELECT id FROM Account WHERE RecordTypeId IN (SELECT id FROM RecordType WHERE name =:accountType)])
    {
        accId.add(a.id);
    }

    favorites = [SELECT Account.id, Account.Name FROM FavoriteAccounts__c WHERE Account.Id IN :accId];
```